# Explode- Word Parts

Tags: etymology

So I have a project to do and I have searched EVERYWHERE online. What is the root word for "Explode"? I already know 'ex' means 'out of', but I'm not sure that 'plode' is a real root word--Or even a WORD!I need help ASAP, so even if you have a guess/idea, please answer back!

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=explode also if your school has access to the Oxford English Dictionary, that's an excellent source for word roots.

Comment: @KitFox - Interesting.  "The audience exploded with applause" is more the literal use of the term, while "The bomb exploded" is figurative.

Comment: Etymology is easy to find online. Look up "implode" and see what it has in common with "explode." Check out the OED as suggested above. It's online, too.

Comment: Sorry, Ya'll - I rushed a post without realizing you had it under control. Didn't mean to step on your toes.

Comment: @LittleEva - it's perfectly ok to post an answer even if there is one in comments. Comments are temporary by nature. If you *want* to answer the question, please feel free to do so. Good answers are good answers!

Comment: @terpy - the OED is not online for free. But a number of good dictionaries are.

Comment: Thanks, @medica - but, to mix metaphors, I don't want to stand on the shoulders of others to pluck low-hanging fruit--the challenge is negated. Additionally, I want a good reputation here (*as opposed to everywhere else*). Just how temporary *are* the comments?

Comment: Hmm, good question. There are bad questions that deserve to be closed, but good answers can turn the tide and get lots of up votes. I love good answers. There are some meta discussions on this that you might like to read.

Comment: You can delete your own comment any time you choose to. As far as I know, you don 't get to delete anybody else's.  However, if you delete your own Answer, the comments attached to it disappear as well. I think this is discussed in meta also, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @LittleEva, My experience has been that comments have an editable timeframe of 5-6 minutes.

Comment: @HotLicks - no, "the bomb exploded" is the literal use of the English verb "explode". The roots of words are interesting but not always the best guide to the current meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you already searched everywhere online, this may be information you already have, but I'll risk giving it anyway. I found it by Googling for "etymology explode" and from there looking at one of the results near the top, namely: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/explode. But the Google results page itself provides the details too:

"plode" seems to be rooted in the Latin "*plaudere*", to clap.